# Removing values from set in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set

I'm trying to write a script for work that tells me which machines on a network are online and which are offline.

Currently I have it showing me online/offline status, taking the PC names from a text file as input into a set variable.

The code I have so far is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (VC.txt) do call :append %%a

:ping
for %%i in (%VC) do (
 ping %%1 -n 1 >nul
 call :test %%i
)
echo.
goto :ping

:test
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
 echo Pinging %1
) else (
 echo Off %1
)
goto :eof

:append
if defined VC (
 set VC=%VC% %1
) else (
 set VC=%1
)
```

What I want to happen is once a machine comes online, to remove it from the list. Basically just only show the list of the offline machines.
Is this possible without wiping the whole set and creating it fresh?

Comment: Design question: just because a machine came online doesn't mean it will stay online.  Help me understand why you don't need to re-scan the entire list of machines at whatever your polling interval is?   Additional thought: do you need to keep "history" stats? e.g. average uptime for a given machine, total outage time for machines.  Doing this in a  "batch" file seems sub optimal, but you probably have a good reason for that.  Anyway, sorry I can't help with your exact question.  *shrug* good luck.

Comment: There are two typos: `for %%i in (%VC) do` should read `for %%i in (%VC%) do` (missing `%` sign), and `ping %%1 -n 1` should read `ping %%i -n 1`...

Comment: @jgeve, The list gets re-scanned constantly to make sure machines stay online. And no, I don't need any history. Basically I need to copy a file to a machine as soon as it's online so this helps me keep track of them.

Comment: @aschipfl, thanks for that. I did have them in my code (it did work), but I had to retype it into the question for formatting and must've missed it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mod do what you want:

```
:test
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
 echo Pinging %1
 REM Remove this machine from the list
 set "VC=!VC: %1=!"
) else (
 echo Off %1
)
goto :eof
```

However, you have a couple small errors in your code. This is the fixed section:

```
:ping
for %%i in (%VC%) do (
 ping %%i -n 1 >nul
 call :test %%i
)
echo.
goto :ping
```

A couple points unrelated to your problem. If the machine names are single words with no spaces, then the `"tokens=*"` part in the `for` command is not needed. Also, all those `call`'s and subroutines just complicate the code. This is the way I would do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "VC="
for /F %%a in (VC.txt) do set "VC=!VC! %%a"

:ping
for %%i in (%VC%) do (
   ping %%i -n 1 >nul
   IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
      echo Pinging %%i
      REM Remove this machine from the list
      set "VC=!VC: %%i=!"
   ) else (
      echo Off %%i
   )
)
echo/
if defined VC goto :ping

echo All machines are on line
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks heaps.